# Mostrar imágenes sobresaliendo la primera de ellas - PHP

Tags: php, html, imagen

Dispongo de una colección de imágenes sobre una cabaña guardadas en un array.
Lo que deseo es que cuando se haga una consulta o búsqueda de ellas mostrar la primera de ellas en un tamaño superior al resto, y el resto de ellas en un tamaño inferior a la primera (al lado de la primera) y que seleccionando las restantes cambiar la primera por la elegida.

Un ejemplo como podemos ver en la siguiente imagen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He probado con las siguientes instrucciones pero no funciona.

```
$imagenes = $cabana->getImagenes();
//Recorremos el foreach del array "$imagenes".
foreach($imagenes as $imagen){
    if(current($imagenes)){
        echo "<img src='imagenes/".$imagen."' width='260' height='260'/> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
    }else{
        echo "<img src='imagenes/".$imagen."' width='140' height='140'/> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
    }
}
```

**Además, ¿cómo ocuparía el lugar de la imagen principal/grande la imagen que seleccione? ¿Un evento onclick sobre la imagen?**

Imagen demostrativa de como me salen (todas mismo tamaño):
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Esto no se podría hacer con php tendría que ser con js dado que ya es del lado del cliente

Comment: Si muestro las imágenes con PHP podría también seleccionar la imagen principal con PHP. Otra cosa es el evento de click en la imagen con "onclick" desde Javascript (lado cliente).

Comment: entonces tu pregutna es mostrar la imagen principal del lado derecho, que me imagino es la de width 260?

Comment: Si mi pregunta es: ¿Cómo hago para mostrar en un tamaño superior al resto (por ejemplo, 260px) la primera imagen del array imágenes y al lado, en tamaño inferior, las restantes? Dicha información extraida de una consulta SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta con esto.

```
$imagenes = $cabana->getImagenes();
//Recorremos el foreach del array "$imagenes".
$first = true;
foreach($imagenes as $imagen){
    if($first){
        echo "<img src='imagenes/".$imagen."' width='260' height='260'/> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
        $first = false;
    }else{
        echo "<img src='imagenes/".$imagen."' width='140' height='140'/> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias. Primera parte superada. No conocía la instrucción "first". Creía que se podría realizar con [0] o current().

Comment: No es una función, si te das cuenta lo que hice fue declarar una variable $first como true, después una vez que entro la primera vez, la cambie a false por lo que ya no entra al if en la segunda iteración, es una variable que tu la puedes llamar como se te de la gana,  para lo que quieres que se vea como el de la foto puedes inspeccionar el código fuente y ver como le hizo para ordenar así las imagenes